# SFDX: retrieve Source from Org failing

Tags: vs-code, sfdx-plugin, cli

In order to connect my VSC to my org and pull my org's datas to VSC, I followed the steps [this great video shows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-9ILFRqcwg) ;

In Visual Studio Code I :
- SFDX: created project with Manifest
- in the manifest -> package.xml, I replaced the code with the one I got using [packagebuilder.herokuapp.com](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/)
- SFDX: authorized (my) Org

Then, exactly as in the video (precisely there [10m10s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-9ILFRqcwg#t=10m10s)), I access the button SFDX: retrieve Source from Org (cf screenshot)
[image].

Then, it's working for several minutes, but finally fail explaining :

```
ERROR:  Expected metadata file at path: (+path)
```

[image]

I search for answers on the internet, after searching there in vain...
Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks !

Edit : 
also tried using the windows commandLine, same result :
[image]

I was looking at [this](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model) topic. Sorry it didn't help..

Edit : I commented the concerned lines :
[image]

And know, I got much more topics to read, as this error seems more common..
But any help is always welcom !

After 8m30s of work, the new error is :

```
ERROR:  EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read.
```

[image]

EDIT !
Well, in fact I got some datas from the org !
But it seems that a lot is missing ... As I don't know which one are missing, and the others, it's not helpful.

Comment: Sadly, I abandonned this way of achieving my goal ; I did it with the help of ForceCode.
Hate not to understand what went wrong, but can't stay like this !

Comment: the space separator in your windows username could be the cause

Comment: also, be aware that the nodejs error `EISDIR` occurs when you try to open a file, but the path given is a folder

Comment: Good to know, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error for pull & retrieve requests. You need to uninstall Salesforce CLI and re-install it.

Comment: This should go as a comment and not answer.

Comment: hey Dorukan Gurek - what steps did you take to reinstall? I have similar issue, i followed these steps: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm, but the issue remains for me.  I am also seeking help in https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/2841

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r metadata -u <alias name> -k <package.xml location>
```

```
-u: Username or alias of the connected Salesforce Org
-r: Location where zip file should be saved
-k: location of the package.xml
```

Here, metadata is the folder name where the retrieved metadata zip file is to be stored (retrieved metadata will be downloaded as a .zip file). As you can see in the above image, metadata/unpackaged.zip is downloaded from the connected org as part of the sfdx retrieve command.

Explained on point 4 of https://techevangel.com/2018/07/26/deploy-retrieve-metadata-using-salesforce-dx-and-vs-code/